# No puedo quitar las comillas ni comas desde url json desde python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando extraer todas las fechas de una skin en especifico con python todo bien, pero lo genera con comas y comillas...

Aquí una imagen de muestra:
[image: skinFortnite]

Este es el código qué estoy usando:

```
import requests


url = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=palito%20de%20pescado%20de%20gominola&searchLanguage=es")

historialSKIN= url.json()


for i in historialSKIN["data"]:
    print(i['shopHistory'])
```

Me gustaria poder quitar esto y que quede en una lista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es "desempaquetar" el elemento del objeto que se genera con `historialSKIN`.

Para ello usa el operador `*` en el `print` y agregarle un separador personalizado. Por ejemplo yo usare el `tab` (`\t`).

```
import requests

separator = '\t'
url = requests.get(
        "https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=palito%20de%20pescado%20de%20gominola&searchLanguage=es"
)

historialSKIN= url.json()

for i in historialSKIN["data"]:
    print(*i['shopHistory'], sep=separator)
```

el cual me da esta salida:

[image: test1]

si gustas puedes hacer el cambio `separator='; '` y la salida seria:

[image: test2]